# helm --post-renderer not working when ran via typescript / node child_process

Tags: node.js, kubernetes-helm, child-process, cat, kustomize

We're invoking helm command inside a typescript program like so

```
child_process.spawn("helm", args, ...);
```

where `args` is something like

```
[ 
  'template', 
  'myapp', 
  '.', 
  '--post-renderer', 
  '/home/script/helm-kustomize.sh'
]
```

`helm-kustomize.sh` is

```
#!/bin/bash
cat <&0 > all.yaml
kustomize build . && rm all.yaml
```

The above does NOT work.

But doing either of the following will work as expected:

1. Run the helm command on a terminal and not via typescript like

   ```
   helm template myapp . --post-renderer /home/script/helm-kustomize.sh
   ```
2. Change `cat <&0 > all.yaml` to `more > all.yaml` (this works even via typescript)

---

Why is the helm command not working when run via typescript? We've tried other `child_process` functions like `spawnSync`, `exec/Sync`, `execFile/Sync` but nothing works. Also tried changing `stdio`, `shell` but nothing worked.

Thanks in advance!